# C: Read a file and store them into a data structure

Tags: c

So I have a .txt doc with the following information (it can be multiple lines, but in this case it is 3 lines)

```
Jane Smith    123 lala land    123-222-1231
Bob Fall    123 blue jay st    812-923-1111
Sally White    1 rose ave.    +1-231-2318
```

I want to create a 'read' function that reads the file, then a 'write' function that writes it into a data structure.

So far , I have this:

```
void read()
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("fileName", "r");
    write(file);
}

void write(FILE *file)
 {

 }
```

I was wondering how I would store each line into a data structure since C does not support vectors. I want to be able to then create a print function where it can print:

```
  1 //line #1 info here
  2 //etc
  3 //etc
```

Comment: You can use a hastable to store and query the records.

Comment: What do you mean with Data Structure? Can you provide an example?

Comment: You need to read whole lines, and split fields based on multiple adjacent spaces. You haven't shown us your structure. You have a function called `write()` (not a good choice of name in the first place) that reads from the file and somehow stores data in your array of structures. The `read()` function (similarly not a good choice of name) opens a file but doesn't check that it was successful or close it before returning. You need to spend a bit more time fleshing out your code before you come here with questions, really, or you need to be a lot more specific about where your problems are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First You open the document file using the `open` or `fopen` function.

eg: `fp=fopen (filename,"r");`

Then read line by line using `fgets`.

eg: `while(fgets(array,BUFSIZ,fp) != NULL)`

After reading each line store the data in the structure using the `sscanf` function.

eg: `sscanf(array," %d  %s`", &var[i].id,var[i].name);`

The data in the file will be loaded in the structure.

Comment: What about the phone number? What delimiter are you relying on the split each field? What happens if the number of spaces between the name, address, and number isn't constant?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you can use the character array for the mobile number and even though the number of space is not constant, `sscanf` will take the default delimiter as `space`.

Comment: Sharon, using `sscanf` and `%s`, reading stops at the first whitespace encountered unless a fixed `width` specifier` is used... So `sscanf` will not work here to parse the `name` or `address` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to parse string that contains spaces, which are in turn separated from other fields by more spaces (e.g `name` and `address`), you **cannot** read the line and then parse the string with `sscanf`. It simply isn't possible. With `scanf/sscanf` the match of a string terminates on the first `whitespace` (unless a `width` specifier is given), rendering it useless for parsing strings of varying length containing whitespace. E.g.:

```
Jane Smith    123 lala land    123-222-1231
```

Attempting to parse with `%s` reads `Jane` and no more. Unless you are guaranteed of a fixed width column, `sscanf` will not work in this case.

Compounding the problem, not only do the strings contain spaces, but the delimiters are composed of multiple-spaces. So unfortunately, this is a situation where you must use pointers to parse the string. How? Start with **known** information.

The only thing that makes this possible is presumption that **the phone number contains no-whitespace**. So using `strrchr` (or set a pointer at the end of the string and backup) you can simply find the space before the start of the phone number. Set an `end pointer (ep)` prior to this space, advance the original pointer by `1` and copy the phone number to the structure.

Starting at `ep`, work backwards until you find the first non-space character (end of the address field) and set a `null-terminating` character there.

The next known point is the beginning of the string. Start there and find the first `double-space`. (the presumption being that the name, address and phone fields are all separated **by at least 2 spaces**). You know the first of the double-space is the end of the name field, set a `null-terminating` character there. (you can read/copy name to the struct at this point by simply reading the start of the string)

Finally, work forward until you find the next non-space character. This is the start of the address. Copy the address to the struct and you are done. (repeat process for each line).

Sometimes where you have no sane delimiter, you have to fall-back to simply stepping through the string with a pointer and processing it piecemeal. This is one of those cases. Look over the following and let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EMAX 128

typedef struct entry {
    char name[32];
    char address[32];
    char phone[16];
} entry;

size_t readtxtfile (char *fn, entry *array);
void prn_entries (entry *array);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* validate number of arguments */
    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s <filename1>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* initialize all variables */
    size_t index = 0;
    entry contacts[EMAX] = {{{0}, {0}, {0}}};

    /* read file into an array of entries,
    number of entries, returned to index */
    index = readtxtfile (argv[1], contacts);

    /* simple print function */
    if (index > 0)
    {
        printf ("\nNumber of entries in contacts : %zu\n\n", index);
        prn_entries (contacts);
    }
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no entries read from file '%s'\n.", argv[1]);

    return 0;
}

size_t readtxtfile (char *fn, entry *array)
{
    if (!fn) return 0;              /* validate filename provided       */

    char *ln = NULL;                /* NULL forces getline to allocate  */
    size_t n = 0;                   /* max chars to read (0 - no limit) */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;               /* number of chars actually read    */
    size_t idx = 0;                 /* couner for number of entries     */
    FILE *fp = NULL;                /* file pointer to open file fn     */

    /* open / validate file */
    if (!(fp = fopen (fn, "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: file open failed '%s'.", __func__, fn);
        return 0;
    }

    /* read each line from file */
    while ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, fp)) != -1)
    {
        /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */
        while (nchr > 0 && (ln[nchr-1] == '\n' || ln[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            ln[--nchr] = 0;

        /* create a copy of ln to preserve start address */
        char *lcpy = strdup (ln);
        if (!lcpy) {
            fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: memory allocation failed.\n", __func__);
            continue;
        }

        char *p = strrchr (lcpy, ' ');                  /* find last space in line      */
        char *ep = p - 1;                               /* set end pointer 1 before     */

        p++;                                            /* advance to next char         */
        strncpy (array[idx].phone, p, strlen (p));      /* copy p to phone              */

        while (ep > lcpy && *ep == ' ') ep--;           /* find first space after addr  */
        *(++ep) = 0;                                    /* null-terminat at that space  */

        p = lcpy;           /* start at beginning of string and find first double-space */
        while (*(p + 1) && !(*(p + 1) == ' ' && *p == ' ')) p++;

        *p = 0;                     /* null-terminate at first space    */

        while (*(++p) == ' ');      /* find first char in addr          */

        strncpy (array[idx].address, p, strlen (p));    /* copy p to address            */
        strncpy (array[idx].name, lcpy, strlen (lcpy)); /* copy lcpy to name            */

        free (lcpy);                /* free memory allocated by strdup  */
        lcpy = NULL;                /* reset pointer NULL               */

        idx++;                      /* increment entry index            */
        if (idx == EMAX)            /* check if EMAX reached & return   */
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "%s() warning: maximun number of entries read\n", __func__);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (ln) free (ln);              /* free memory allocated by getline */
    if (fp) fclose (fp);            /* close open file descriptor       */

    return idx;
}

/* print an array of character pointers. */
void prn_entries (entry *array)
{
    register size_t n = 0;
    while (strlen (array[n].name) > 0)
    {
        printf (" (%2zu.)  %-32s %-32s %s\n", n, array[n].name, array[n].address, array[n].phone);
        n++;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/read_entries dat/nmaddph.txt

Number of entries in contacts : 3

 ( 0.)  Jane Smith                       123 lala land                    123-222-1231
 ( 1.)  Bob Fall                         123 blue jay st                  812-923-1111
 ( 2.)  Sally White                      1 rose ave.                      +1-231-2318
```

**Note:** using `getline` or any time you have allocated space for a string dynamically, you need to make a copy before you alter that memory block with functions that do not preserve the original start of the string (like `strtok` or you manually iterating over the string with the string variable). `getline` allocates the memory for `ln` for you (if originally set NULL) and as a result `getline` is responsible for freeing it. If you alter the start address for the string, or leave parts of it unreachable, then when `getline` attempts to `realloc` or `free` that block of memory, a memory error will occur. Making a copy will save you a lot of headaches.

In the example above, a copy of the `ln` allocated by `getline` is made. Character pointers are assigned as needed **to preserve the starting address** of `lcpy`. If you would have iterated over the string advancing `lcpy` (e.g. `lcpy++;`), instead of using a second pointer, the original start address would be lost. When you (or the program on exit) attempts to free `lcpy` a whole host of errors (or segmentation faults) can occur.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAXLENGTH 200 
typedef struct node{
    char query[MAXLENGTH];
}DATA;

typedef struct stack{
    DATA data[MAXLENGTH];
    int top;
}Stack;

void write(FILE *file,Stack* st)
{   
    while(!feof(file)){  //Check EOF
        st->top++; 
        fgets(st->data[st->top].query,MAXLENGTH,file); //Scan data line by line and put into data structure
        //printf("%s",st->data[st->top].query); 
    }
}

void read(Stack* st)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("h.txt", "r");
    write(file,st);
}

int main(){
    int i;
    Stack st;
    st.top = -1;

    read(&st);

    for(i = 0; i<= st.top; i++){  //DISPLAY DATA
        printf("%s\n",st.data[i].query); 
    } 
    fflush(stdin);getchar();
    return 0;
}
```